# Ignore spaces and punctuation for VAT number using Regex

Tags: regex, expression

I'm a newbie at regex and I'm trying to ignore spaces and punctuation when validating the format of a VAT number.

I have this regular expression: `^BE[0-9]{10,10}$`

It works for this: **BE1234567890**

But I need it to work for these too:

- BE 1234567890
- BE 123.456.7890
- BE:1234567890
- etc.

How can I get the Regex to ignore whitespaces and punctuation that I define?

Comment: This is easily achieved without a regex, so unless it's of academic interest there are other approaches that you might consider. (Though a regex may be a good approach, it's easy to make mistakes with regex and introduce bugs - it's a very powerful tool to use for simple cases like this)

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot create a canonical version (e.g. upper-case, with whitespace and your selected punctuation removed) first and then just validate what remains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better idea would be just to strip all spaces and punctuation beforehand, then validate the stripped string with your regex.

But if you really want to, you can do this:

```
^BE([[:space:][:punct:]]*[0-9]){10}$
```

This allows arbitrary spaces/punctuation before each digit.

Comment: You are a god among men. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

BE(\s?|:)(\d{10}|\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{3,4})

this is for EXCACTLY your given examples. Note that you might match more digits in the last \d{3,4} to fulfill your needs